# Visual Studio 2012 Web Publish keeps overwriting existing files with same version

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Just installed VS2012 and run across a strange behavior by the one click publish feature.

I'm publishing via FTP and everything works fine except it seems that VS insists on overwriting some files over and over even though nothing's changed.

In VS2010 clicking the "publish" button over and over just runs through the steps and finishes in a few seconds, in VS2012 it takes about two minutes as it keeps copying a 5mb dll and some other stuff too.

P.S the "delete all existing files prior to publish" is off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an absolute pain. I've resorted to keeping the solution open in VS2010 alongside the VS2012 and using VS2010 to publish, it's annoying, but it's faster...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no option for only changed files in VS 2012. Not sure why they took it out, other than maybe too many people complained that VS wasn't synching properly when their FTP servers were the problem. FTP servers are notorious for not giving back correct file info.

Comment: What a real P.I.T.A...  Publishing is taking forever now.

Answer (score 0):

This is real too slow on large amount of files.
My best experience is to remove unused folders not containing assemblies (scripts, css, etc...) this way `<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>Content;Scripts;Views</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>`
.
Publish  these files straight when you change them . Otherwise publish assemblies from profile .
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158.aspx#can_i_exclude_specific_files_or_folders_from_deployment